# LINQ/Lambda to Binary Tree

Tags: linq, lambda, tree, linq-to-objects

I'm looking for a way to select from a binary tree (AVL or B tree) using Lambda without running through all the nodes in the tree.

Any suggestions or interesting links?

Comment: It's not clear what you've already got, or what you're trying to do. Could you give an example?

Comment: Tree:
            5
          4   7
        3    6  8
      2           10

Something like this.

If i want to find 6 i'd do {x => x == 6}. If this had been a list i would just run through the list and fire the lambda expression on the object. But i would need to run through all the objects since this is equal or not.
A tree is found, left or right. How would this be done? or is i get an even more advanced lambda like x => x == 6 || x==4 && (x>2 || x<3)

Does this make any sence?

Comment: numbers would be in a binary tree (5 4 7 3 6 8 2 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your binary tree to take advantage of the structure it knows it has to provide improved performance when queried with LINQ, you need to implement an `IQueryProvider`.

There's an excellent series of blog posts on that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx), but this is not something to be undertaken lightly.